# Find the sum of $2^{-x}/x$

Tags: summation

> Task is the following: find the $\sum_{x=1}^{+∞} \frac{2^{-x}}x$

I don't even know how to proceed. I know that $\sum_{x=1}^{+∞} 2^{-x} = 1$. However, is it useful here?

Comment: The sum is equal to $$\log(2)$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes, I know the answer. I don't know how to get it.

Comment: I would consider $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n}/n$ instead. The variable $x$ is usually considered to be continuous. Hint: Start with $\sum_{n=1}^ \infty x^n$, which is known.  Then replace $x$ with $x/2$ to get powers of $2$. Then think about what kind of operation you can do to get the $n$ in the denominator.  (Think about different things you can do in calculus...)

Comment: use taylor expansion for $ln(1/2)$

Comment: Use [this series for the natural logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Series) and plug for $x= -1/2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a neat trick. Note that

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\alpha} \sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{2^{-\alpha x}}{x} = -\ln(2)\sum_{x=1}^\infty 2^{-\alpha x} = -\ln(2)\frac{2^{-\alpha}}{1-2^{-\alpha}}$$

Now integrate this from $\alpha=1$ to $\alpha=\infty$:

$$ - \sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{2^{-x}}{x}= \left. -\ln\left(1 - 2^{-\alpha}\right) \right|_{\alpha =1}^\infty =  -\ln(2)$$

Answer (score 4):

According to Taylor's series,

$$\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+\cdots,  ~~~\forall x \in (-1,1].$$

Let $x=-\dfrac{1}{2}.$ Then $$\ln \frac{1}{2}=\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)=-\dfrac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2 \cdot 2^2}-\frac{1}{3 \cdot 2^3}-\frac{1}{4 \cdot 2^4}+\cdots=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\cdot 2^n}
$$
Therefore
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\cdot 2^n}=-\ln\frac{1}{2}=\ln2.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1:** It suffices to recognize this sum as a Taylor series

**Hint 2:** It is in fact sufficient to know that for all $x \in (-1,1)$, we have
$$
\sum_{x=1}^\infty z^{x-1} = \frac{1}{1-z}
$$
Note that for $z = 1/2$, this is your statement.  It follows that
$$
\int_{0}^t \frac{1}{1-z}\,dz = \int_{0}^t \sum_{x=1}^\infty z^{x-1}dz = 
\sum_{x=1}^\infty \int_{0}^t  z^{x-1}dz = \sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{t^x}{x}
$$